# Multi-country website with multi-lingual selection with Joomla 3.5.1

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system

I'm handling a multi-lingual website, that works fine, but after a new request I have to implement a multi country choice which allow users to select, first of all, them nation and after the prefered language.
I have to manage less than five countries (Italy, Germany, Uk and China) and all of those should offer the possibility to chose between three languages (the native tongue of the nation and two others).

You can quickly get the point here, (top menu, on the left): https://www.sick.com/nl/en/

I've already found  good advices online, like "do one installation per country with a different base url and then make each of them multilingual as you wish.
It can be a sub-domain or a sub folder." That could be a great solution and I'm going to try it using the subfolder way because the website is one domain.

Now I'm wondering if the subfolder name can be: EN (website.com/en) - DE (website.com/de)...the other mainly problem is if possible to join all of those joomla installations?

I hope someone will help me.

A big thank you in advance!